# The %element-title is using the following invalid tokens

Tags: 7, tokens

I have defined few tokens that are grouped in few separate groups similar to `[node:content-type:name]` scheme. For example I'd like to have a token like `[master:sub_group_1:tokan_A]`. So This is how `hook_token_info()` looks like:

```
function MY_MODULE_token_info() {
  $tokens = array();
  $types = array();

  $types['master'] = array(
    'name' => 'Master group',
    'description' => 'This is the master group',
  );

  $types['sub_group_1'] = array(
    'name' => 'Sub group 1',
    'description' => 'This is the first sub group',
    // this tells this group that it's parent is 'master' group.
    'needs-data' => 'master',
  );

  $tokens['sub_group_1']['token_A'] = array(
    'name' => 'Token A',
    'description' => 'This token prints letter A',
  );

  return array(
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => $tokens,
  );
}
```

I'll skip `MY_MODULE_tokens()` as it's irrelevant here, but `token_replace()` works perfectly. It replaces `[master:sub_group_1:token_A]` correctly. But the problem is that `token` module does not list my custom tokens in *available tokens* section and when I try to use `[master:sub_group_1:token_A]` in forms that get validated by `token` module, I get `The %element-title is using the following invalid tokens` error message.

What is the correct method to define custom tokens and group them to avoid conflicts with tokens defined by other modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in order to nest those tokens a "dummy" token is needed that matches group name:

```
function MY_MODULE_token_info() {
  $tokens = array();
  $types = array();

  $types['master'] = array(
    'name' => 'Master group',
    'description' => 'This is the master group',
  );

  // This is needed in order to nest tokens:
  // a dummy token that is the same as nested group/type
  $tokens['master']['sub_group_1'] = array(
    'name' => 'Sub group 1',
    'description' => '1st tokens group',
    'type' => 'sub_group_1',
  );

  $types['sub_group_1'] = array(
    'name' => 'Sub group 1',
    'description' => 'This is the first sub group',
    // this tells this group that it's parent is 'master' group.
    'needs-data' => 'master',
  );

  $tokens['sub_group_1']['token_A'] = array(
    'name' => 'Token A',
    'description' => 'This token prints letter A',
  );

  return array(
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => $tokens,
  );
}
```